# impyla : how to setup mem_limit?

Tags: python-3.8, impyla

I'm using impyla==0.16.2 on python 3.8.3

Tried to execute `set mem_limit=1G`

and after running query it does still give the error of mem_limit.

That should be resolved because If I follow the same steps on Dbeaver it works as expected.

Not sure why its not working in impyla.

Can someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

To Setup mem_limit using impala, pass it as confiruration parameter in cursor.execute statements.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, configuration={'mem_limit': '1G'})
```

Query will run successfully.